# yii2 filter results using parameter against multiple records in another table

Tags: php, yii2

I want to be able to filter records that are returned within my PostSearch model using data stored with my posttocategory join table, I currently have a list of links which have the following href /posts?cat=somenumber

---

**Example Database Setup**

**Posts Table:**
-id
-title
-content

**Post To Category (Join Table):**
-id
-post_id
-category_id

**Category:**
-id
-title

---

**Current controller setup:**

```
    $pageSize = 12;

    $published = true;

    $searchModel = new PostsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $pageSize, $published);
```

---

**Posts Model Relation (retrieves related category data)**

```
public function getPostCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostCategories::className(), ['id' => 'category_id'])
        ->viaTable('categories_to_posts', ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: you can remove join table and add `category_id` to `posts` table itself.

Comment: @InsaneSkull but a post can be attached to multiple categories therefore join table allows for a many to many relationship?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What is your goal and what is the problem with your current approach?